# How to reorder WPF Toolkit datagrid colums programmatically?

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit, wpfdatagrid

My application uses the WPF DataGrid control with custom columns. Although the property Columns is an ObservableCollection<>, the invocation of the method Move does not effect the order of the columns in any way.

Can I somehow reorder the columns of a WPF Toolkit DataGrid programmatically?

Best Regards
Oliver Hanappi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [DisplayIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn_members%28VS.100%29.aspx) property of a DataGridColumn (use datagrid.Columns to retrieve the columns collection).